# Best way to check 3 variable values equals to zero inside if condition - PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I am checking 3 variables are equals to zero inside if condition , currently i am doing some thing like this

```
if($diff_colour_code==0 && $diff_upholstery_code==0 && $big_diff==0 )
```

is there any better way to do this

I am thinking a way like

```
if($diff_colour_code==$diff_upholstery_code==$big_diff==0 )
```

Please help , Thanks in advance .

Comment: if your variables only contains integers, you can add them together and check if the result is 0

Comment: no , variables can take minus values :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

You can give the function as many arguments as you need!

```
<?php

    $diff_colour_code = 0;
    $big_diff = 0;
    $diff_upholstery_code = 0;

    function zeroCheck() {
        foreach(func_get_args() as $arg)
            if($arg == 0)
                continue;
            else
                return false;
        return true;
    }


    if (zeroCheck($diff_colour_code, $big_diff, $diff_upholstery_code))
        echo "all are 0!";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `!` as :

```
if(!$diff_colour_code && !$diff_upholstery_code && !$big_diff )
```

Comment: value should be specifically 0 , i think '' and false will pass this statement

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
   $var1 = 0;
   $var2 = 0;
   $var3 = 0;

   $array = compact("var1", "var2", "var3");
   $countValues = array_count_values($array);
    if($countValues[0] == count($array)){
        echo "yes";
    }else{
        echo "no";
    }
```

or this

```
 if(($var1 == 0 && $var1 == $var2 && $var2 == $var3)){
        echo "yes";
   }else{
        echo "no";
   }
```